# Single machine scheduling with profit and deadline constraints

Tags: dynamic-programming, np-hard, scheduling, maximum-subarray

The problem is described as such:

Given $n$ tasks $\{J_1, \ldots , J_n\}$where each task has a deadline and a ‘profit’.

So for some $i \in \{1,\ldots , n\}$, $J_i=\{t_i,p_i\}$ where $t_i$ is the deadline to complete the task, and $p_i$ is the expected profit.

It is given that:

- starting time is $0$
- each task takes $1$ time to complete.
- you can only work on a single task in every time unit.

The goal is to describe an efficient algorithm to receive a group of n task as input (as described) and finds the maximal profit subseries of tasks.

I know this problem relates to a family of problems where a machine can only perform a single task every time, and since this problem requires to find the maximal subseries, I’m inclined towards a dynamic programming approach, yet I also consider a greedy approach might do the trick.

I was unable to find a solution to the problem with such constraints.

Comment: @Dmitry Oops, you're right. So it's $1 \mid p_i = 1 \mid \sum w_j U_j$ and it's a lot easier. [This table](https://www2.informatik.uni-osnabrueck.de/knust/class/dateien/classes/ein_ma/ein_ma/) gives a reference for a polynomial solution: Baptiste, Philippe. "Polynomial time algorithms for minimizing the weighted number of late jobs on a single machine with equal processing times." Journal of Scheduling 2.6 (1999): 245-252.

Comment: I think you can just solve it using linear programming (with variables $x_{ij}$ being "assign task $i$ to time $j$"). The only concern is whether the solution is integer, and, as I understand, this part is fine since the incidence matrix for bipartite graphs is unimodular (see e.g. https://theory.stanford.edu/~jvondrak/MATH233B-2017/lec3.pdf)

Comment: I can't access the article I mentioned, but a dynamic solution shouldn't be too complex. Note that choosing a solution for the problem basically amounts to choosing which jobs will be on-time and which jobs will be late. Indeed, once you have chosen a list of on-time jobs, you can without loss of generality order these jobs in order of due date.

Comment: @Stef I believe the profit is different for every task.
Also, in the table you've shared, there is no solution described for $1|p_i=1|\sum w_j U_j$

Comment: If you think about it as "which task assign to which time", then it becomes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem (if a task is assigned to the time beyond the deadline, the profit is 0).

Comment: @Dmitry I'm confused, aren't we looking to only choose a subseries of the tasks which yields maximal profit? 
Of course that such subseries united with tasks we didnt complete (basically the rest) which are completed past their deadlines still yields maximal profit.
So if I'm getting this correctly, I'm suppose to output a permutation of $\{J_1, \ldots , J_n\}$? not just a subseries $J' \subseteq J$?

Comment: Yes, permutation of the entire set of jobs.

Comment: Yes, the profit is different for every task, that's what the $w_j$ stand for in the notation $\sum w_j U_j$. If the profits were all the same it would just be $\sum U_j$. My point was: There exists a solution such that jobs $i_1, i_2, i_3, ..., i_k$ are on-time if and only if those jobs are on-time when they are ordered in order of due date. So, you should take the profits into account when deciding which jobs you want to be on-time, but once you have decided that, you can order these jobs in order of due date without loss of generality: you no longer need to take their profits into account.

Comment: There is $1 \mid p_i=1, \, r_i \mid \sum w_j U_j$ in the table I shared; and $1 \mid p_i=1 \mid \sum w_j U_j$ is a particular case of $1 \mid p_i=1, \, r_i \mid \sum w_j U_j$ (because $1 \mid p_i=1 \mid \sum w_j U_j$ is the same as $1 \mid p_i=1, \, r_i=0 \mid \sum w_j U_j$). So, if the table says that $1 \mid p_i=1, \, r_i \mid \sum w_j U_j$ can be solved in polynomial time, then the particular case $1 \mid p_i=1 \mid \sum w_j U_j$ can be solved in polynomial time, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple greedy algorithm is known for this problem [1].

First, sort jobs by non-decreasing order of deadline. Let $S := \emptyset$ be a variable to denote a set of jobs. Then, for each job $i$,

```
if |S| < t_i then:
  Add job i to S
  # Job i is scheduled at time |S|-1
else if there exists a job k in S such that p_k < p_i:
  Delete job k from S such that p_k is minimal
  Add job i to S
  # Job i is scheduled at the time job k was scheduled
```

By implementing the set $S$ using a priority queue, the algorithm runs in $O(n \log n)$ time. This algorithm can be generalized to the case of identical parallel machines.

The greedy algorithm can be understood as an incremental greedy algorithm for the [matroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid).

- [1] Brucker, Peter. Scheduling Algorithms. 5th ed. Springer, 2007.

Comment: How can we be sure that when we remove job $k$ and adding job $i$ instead, $t_i$ is within $|S|$?

Comment: @Aishgadol $|S|$ is not relevant here. Let $p_i$ be the scheduled time of job $i$ then we need $p_i < t_i$. We have $p_k < t_k$ by induction. Also $t_k \leq t_i$ because we have sorted the jobs. Thus $p_i = p_k < t_k \leq t_i$.

Comment: I see. Thank you for sharing this solution, it truly helped me to deepen my understanding of this problem.  If we were to have 2, or $k$ machines working simultaneously, how would the algorithm change? How would this affect time complexity?

Comment: @Aishgadol The parallel-machine variant has almost the same algorithm. The time complexity the same. The only change is making the set $S$ to have multiplicity $k$ so the check $|S| < t_i$ will become $|S|/k < t_i$ for example.